# inconsistent navigation timeouts with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I'm using async/await to run 10 crawlers in parallel with headless Chrome & the puppeteer library, but I keep getting inconsistent timeouts with this code.  Sometimes all 10 webpages do fine, and other times I'll get 7 of them time out after 30 seconds.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function test()
{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();//{headless: false}

    var sites = ['http://bbcnews.com','http://yahoo.com','http://cnn.com','http://quora.com','http://imgur.com','http://youtube.com','http://azure.com','http://kayak.com','http://medium.com','http://reddit.com'];

    var requests = [];
    for (let site of sites)
    {
        requests.push(run(browser, site))
    }
    results = await Promise.all(requests);
}

async function run(browser, site)
{
    try
    {
        var page = await browser.newPage();
        //await page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.9 Safari/536.5")
        //console.log(site);
        await page.goto(site, {
                    /*networkIdleTimeout: 5000,
                    waitUntil: 'networkidle',
                    timeout: 30000*/
                });
        //var screenshot = await page.screenshot();
        await page.close();
        console.log('done' + site)
        }
    catch (err) 
    {
        console.log(err)
        return null;
    }
}

test().catch(console.error.bind(console))
```

Comment: As I developed something similar, I ended up with using child processes and even then I needed to run them in different containers. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: I rarely face this problem even when I run it one-after-another. Did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: You can crawl sites concurrently (https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue) . Like two sites at a same time or etc. You can also make a record of fails site and re-run the crawler for those sites again. I used this way every time.

Comment: 10 crawlers is (potentially) a lot to run at once. Did you try running them sequentially to see if any time out? How about extending the timeouts? Using a queue is smart, as mentioned. Some pages are pretty slow to load, and `networkidle2` can be a bit dangerous if the site keeps too many long-running requests open (unlikely the issue here, or it'd probably always fail, but worth mentioning--it's still slower than the default `"load"` or `"domcontentloaded"`).